# "Missing Type Specifier" error when compiling custom wxWidgets event - Why?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am building a wxWidgets program (C++, Windows) and I have a custom event that I am using for a complex graphics panel.  I would like to put the event in a separate header but when I move it there I start getting compile errors: "Missing Type Specifier" related to a custom class that the event object stores and returns to the event handler.

The weird thing is that it compiles when the event class is in the same header with the custom class (afterwards), but if I move it and #include that header before the event class is defined, the error appears.  I can work around by leaving it where it is, but the header it was in is getting very large and I'd like to break it up a bit.

I'm missing something.  What is it?

This is the relevant code section:

**MyEvent.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <wx/event.h>
#include "MyVisualizer.h"       // For GraphConstraint object.

// *** OTHER UNRELATED EVENT CLASS DECLARATIONS ***

class GraphChangedEvent : public wxCommandEvent
{
public:
    GraphChangedEvent(wxEventType eventtype, int id);
    GraphChangedEvent(const GraphChangedEvent& evt);
    ~GraphChangedEvent();
    wxEvent* Clone() const;
    const GraphConstraint& GetConstraint() const;   // *** MISSING TYPE SPECIFIER HERE ***
    void SetConstraint(const GraphConstraint& constraint);   // *** AND HERE ***
    void SetConstraint(long series, long xmin, long xmax);
private:
    GraphConstraint constraint;    // *** AND HERE ***
};

wxDECLARE_EVENT(MYEVT_GRAPHSELECTED, GraphChangedEvent);
```

**MyVisualizer.h**

```
// *** MISCELLANEOUS #DEFINES AND A COUPLE OF CLASS DEFINITIONS ***

#define MYGRAPH_SERIES_UNDEFINED -1

class GraphConstraint
{
public:
    long series = MYGRAPH_SERIES_UNDEFINED;
    long xmin = -1;
    long xmax = -1;

    GraphConstraint() { series = MYGRAPH_SERIES_UNDEFINED; xmin = -1; xmax = -1; };
    GraphConstraint(long series, long xmin, long xmax) { this->series = series; this->xmin = xmin; this->xmax = xmax; };
    ~GraphConstraint() {};

    void Clear() { series = MYGRAPH_SERIES_UNDEFINED; xmin = -1; xmax = -1; };
    void Copy(const GraphConstraint& gc) { series = gc.series; xmin = gc.xmin; xmax = gc.xmax; };
};
```

Comment: Please include the full error msg.

Comment: Do `MyVisualizer.h` include `MyEvent.h`? Then you have a classical circular include file dependency that you need to break. Typically done with the help of *forward declarations*.

Comment: You might have to use `wxDECLARE_EXPORTED_EVENT` to export the events.

Comment: @TPDMarchHare, did you try to look at the event sample? Tried to modify it to split the custom event in a different file? Did you check the event overview portion in the docs?

Comment: I think the answer to this question is "don't do it that way".

I was creating a circular file dependency (thanks @Someprogrammerdude for pointing that out).  I could have resolved it by moving other portions of the Visualizer code into the Events files, but they're specific to that module of the program and mixing them that way makes things even less organized.

The Visualizer is the only part using the event I was trying to move.  I'll leave it where it was and try not to get annoyed when I scroll past it.